# HR department refuse of job application because family member already works for the company

Tags: job-offer

My HR department have refused an application for a post applied by my sister because i already work for the company and it may conflict with my job role. is this legal?

Comment: Where are you located? Hard to discuss legal questions without knowing the jurisdiction.

Comment: Perhaps. I, as a manager, certainly would not be allowed to hire any relatives.

Comment: Many companies have anti-nepotism rules in place, this one seems a bit extreme but I believe they are legal.

Comment: my guess would be Wales

Comment: I doubt they are breaking any established laws of any country discriminating based on this.  Live with it and move on, you are unlikely to change their mind.

Answer (score 3):

Some companies have a policy about hiring family members. They go beyond anti-nepotism rules. They are looking to avoid situations where having a close relative in the work place will cause a problem.

It can even be an attempt to make sure that they are minimizing an insider threat. Two relatives who have to double check each others work might not be as careful as the company would like. That could cost the company money if something gets missed. It also doesn't provide a second set of eyes that would serve as a deterrent to employee theft.

This is generally addressed in the employee handbook.